# ionic 2: keeps stopping on android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, ionic2

This is my first time writing an ionic 2 app. I have cloned from github a tutorial app and successfully built it on my local pc.

```
$ npm install
$ ionic platform add android
$ ionic build android
```

This command works `$ ionic serve --livereload` (I can run my app in the browser, set breakpoint and debug in visual studio code. Everything works perfectly)

But when I attempt to deploy the app on my android emulator
(target:Android 7.0, cpu/abi: Intel Atom (x86_64), Ram 2048, VN Heap:64), this app craches.

This is the command to deploy app to emulator:

```
$ ionic run android
```

And this is the crach:

[image]

I have looked at many threads over the internet. Some suggest to reinstall every thing. (But `ionic server` works perfectly...). Here are my system specifications:

1. npm:

[image]

2. ionic 2:

[image]

Please any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem with ionic when running on emulator.

I solved it by making sure that the value for FadeSplashScreenDuration and  SplashScreenDelay are set as Integers, instead of doubles in the config.xml file under your ionic project folder.

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the solution you were looking for but lately I had the same problem and couldn't found the solution.

My target on emulator had android 7.0 version (API 24).
It started to working when i created new device with android 6 (API 24).